# How to multiple source in openURL in AppDelegate.m?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to handle both of Twitter and deep link in openURL, using ReactNative.
The code below does not work, ending up go into `if (LinkingHandled)` even when handling Twitter.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)options {
  bool TwitterHandled = [[Twitter sharedInstance] application:application openURL:url options:options];
  bool LinkingHandled =[RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options];
  if (TwitterHandled) {
    return TwitterHandled;
  }
  if (LinkingHandled) {
    return LinkingHandled;
  }
  return NO;
}
```

What is wrong with this? I'm new to ObjC.

Answer (score 1):

Use `} else if {` so only Twitter goes if it gets handled, and 'linking' will only go if `TwitterHandled` is `NO` and `LinkingHandled` is YES.

This can be simplified into one expression:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)options {
    return [Twitter.sharedInstance
            application:application
                openURL:url options:options] || 
           [RCTLinkingManager
            application:application 
                openURL:url
                options:options];
}
```

Switch to Swift if you can.

Comment: Thank you! Why `Twitter.sharedInstance`, not `[Twitter sharedInstance]` ? Does it work expectedly?

Comment: I prefer to use dot syntax whenever possible, usually on properties and getter methods, including singleton ones like `-[sharedInstance]`. I think it's easier to read too.